# JS - dynamically created div containers contain the wrong data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create some divs dynamically. Each div contains an object

```
function node(id, title, content, isPrivate, dateOfCreation) { // my node object
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;
  this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
  this.dateOfCreation = dateOfCreation;
  this.lastEdited = dateOfCreation;
}
```

and this object is managed by my datastore class

```
    var store = new dataStore(); // instance of the store

    function dataStore() {
      this.nodes = []; // all the node objects

      this.getNodes = function() { // get all objects
        return this.nodes;
      }

  this.addNode = function(node) { // add a new object
    addElementToArray(this.nodes, node);
  }

  this.deleteNode = function(node) { // delete an object
    deleteElementFromArray(this.nodes, node)
  }

      this.getNodeById = function(nodeId){ // find an object by its id
        for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
          if(nodeId == this.nodes[i].id)
                return this.nodes[i];
        }
        return null;
      }

      this.getNodeTitle = function(node){ // get the title of the node
        return node.title;
      }
    }
```

So I want to create some divs, one div for each object.

```
function initNodeView() { // build up all the divs

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) { // -- TEST -- Fill the store
      store.addNode(new node(i, i, i, i % 2 == 0, i));
    }

  var nodes = store.getNodes(); // get all the nodes from the store

  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var currentNode = nodes[i]; // the current object

    var nodeContainer = createDiv('#nodeList', "nodeContainer"); // the wrapperdiv

    createDivWithText(nodeContainer, "nodeContentDiv", store.getNodeTitle(currentNode)); // create a child div with the title of the object

    var barContainer = createDiv(nodeContainer, "nodeBtnBarDiv"); // create a childdiv - the container of all buttons

    createDivWithIcon(barContainer, "nodeIcon", currentNode.isPrivate ? "'foo.png'" : "'bar.png'"); // create an icon div

    var btnDefaultCss = "nodeBtn"; // default css class for buttons

    createBtn(barContainer, btnDefaultCss, "Edit", function() {
        // empty ..
    });

    createBtn(barContainer, btnDefaultCss, "Delete", function() {
      nodeContainer.remove(); // remove this container from the DOM
      store.deleteNode(currentNode); // delete this object from the store
    });
  }
}
```

To refactor my code I built up some helper functions.

```
function createDiv(parent, cssClass){ // create default div
    var divElement = $("<div></div>");
    divElement.addClass(cssClass);
    $(parent).append(divElement);
    return divElement;
}

function createDivWithText(parent, cssClass, text){ // create div with text
    var divElement = createDiv(parent, cssClass);
    divElement.html(text);
    return divElement;
}

function createDivWithIcon(parent, cssClass, iconSource){ // create icon div
    var divElement = createDiv(parent, cssClass);
    var icon = $("<img src='"+ iconSource +"'/>");
    divElement.append(icon);
    return divElement;
}

function createBtn(parent, cssClass, text, fn){ // create a new button
    var btn = $("<button></button>");
    btn.addClass(cssClass);
    btn.html(text);
    btn.click(function() {
        fn();
    });
    $(parent).append(btn);
}
```

My problem is, when calling initNodeView() the div containers are built up fine. But when clicking on a button (edit or delete) and want to log the stored object of this container it always got the last object stored in it.

So when creating 30 objects and 30 div containers they all got the 30th object stored in it.

Normally div 1 should have object 1, div 2 object 2, ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Can you share the content of `addElementToArray`? Also, would it possible for you to get rid of functions that are not causing any problem so as to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb `addElementToArray` is most probably just an example (of something like `Array.push`). The problem is the function scopes, like just95 answered.

@ Question3r just a heads up: Class names are capitalized in JS convention https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640506/4621141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JavaScript uses the concept of function scope. This means that every variable declared inside a function is local to the function, but not as you might expect local to the current block of curly brackets. Thus there is only one variable `currentNode` that is assigned a new value in every iteration. But in your event handlers you refer to the same variable, whose final value is the last node.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var currentNode = nodes[i];
  // ...
}
// currentNode == nodes[nodes.length - 1]
```

There are many ways to solve this issue. 
You could wrap the body of your `for`-loop inside an anonymous function and invoke it immediately, to force JavaScript to create a new scope for each iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  (function(currentNode) {
     // ...
  })(nodes[i]);
}
```

Alternatively [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the value of `currentNode` to an argument of the event handlers.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var currentNode = nodes[i];
  // ...
  createBtn(barContainer, btnDefaultCss, "Edit", (function(currentNode) {
    // empty ..
  }).bind(null, currentNode));
}
```

For future projects you might consider the use the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword introduced by [ECMAScript 6](http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedVariables). Variables declared with `let` instead of `var` are scoped as you would expect.

```
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  let currentNode = nodes[i];
  // ...
}
// currentNode is not defined
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let) this feature of JavaScript is implemented in pretty much all major browsers. But for sake of consistency you should avoid to mix `let` and `var`.

Answer (score 0):

So I will just leave some working fiddles here, @just95 answered this very well too.

The first one is working with a seperate function to leave the scope:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var btn = $("<button></button>");
    btn.html(i);
    addClickEvent(btn, i);
    $('.container').append(btn)
}

function addClickEvent(btn, val){
    btn.click(function(){
      alert(val);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

The second way is using the keyword "let" instead of "var"

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 var btn = $("<button></button>");
  btn.html(i);
  btn.click(function(){
   alert(i);
  });
 $('.container').append(btn)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

and the last one might be the best (in my opinion!) by using the jquery function `each`. When using native javascript you can use the [forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) function

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];

$(arr).each(function(index, element){
 var btn = $("<button></button>");
  btn.html(element);
  btn.click(function(){
   alert(index + 1);
  });
 $('.container').append(btn)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```